# Does activepivot support distribution?

Tags: java, activepivot

Suppose that I have too much historical data (data from 2012 and 2011) to be put on one single computer using an activepivot.
Can I split the data among the two computers (one with 2011 data and another with 2012 data) and still have a global view (i.e. the total number of facts in 2011 and 2012)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes! ActivePivot can split data by row (horizontal distribution as you suggest) or also by column (Polymorphic distribution), which could be sales column on one machine and price column on another.

http://quartetfs.com/en/activepivot-distributed-architecture

http://quartetfs.com/products/activepivot/in-memory-computing - "Horizontally Scalable. ActivePivot is scalable as it grows with your business and allows you to benefit from insights on both real-time and historical data. ActivePivot can be deployed on distributed architectures such as clusters and wide area networks."